# Bottom Up Search to Filter a Nested Menu Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion

I have searched on here for bottom-up search examples and I understand how they are done, but I have a specific need here that I have been unable to solve.

We have a menu system that I need to create a filter for.

So for example if the menu is

```
- Testing
    - Test
- Something
    - Something Else
    - Test
```

If I filter for "Test" I want **4 nodes** back and everything else pruned out.   The tricky part is that it can't remove the "Something" node in this case due to it having matching children that need to be accessed.

My code works, but only for the top level items, due to the `filter` pass during the first recursion step removing anything that may have matching children but the parent doesn't match.

```
private recursiveFilter(menuItems: MenuItem[], label: string): MenuItem[] {

if (label === '') {
  this.menuItems = this.originalMenuItems;
  return this.menuItems;
} else if (!menuItems)  {
  return [];
}

return menuItems
  .filter((el) => el.label?.toLowerCase().includes(label.toLowerCase()))
  .map((el) => {

    if (!(el.items || !Array.isArray(el.items))) {
      return el;
    } else {

      const menuChildren = el.items as MenuItem[];

      if (menuChildren) {
        el.items = this.recursiveFilter(menuChildren, label);
      }

      return el;

    }
  });

}
```

Example of a MenuItem with nested children:

```
{
    "label": "Messages",
    "expanded": false,
    "items": [
        {
            "label": "Dashboard",
            "expanded": false,
            "routerLink": "/messages",
            "visible": true
        },
        {
            "label": "Voicemail",
            "expanded": false,
            "items": [
                {
                    "label": "Inbox",
                    "icon": "pi pi-fw pi-folder",
                    "routerLink": "/mailbox/inbox"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Archived",
                    "icon": "pi pi-fw pi-folder",
                    "routerLink": "/mailbox/archived"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Trash",
                    "icon": "pi pi-fw pi-folder",
                    "routerLink": "/mailbox/trash"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "label": "Text",
            "expanded": false,
            "items": [
                {
                    "label": "Messages",
                    "routerLink": "/sms",
                    "routerLinkActiveOptions": {
                        "exact": true
                    }
                },
                {
                    "label": "Send",
                    "routerLink": "/sms/send",
                    "routerLinkActiveOptions": {
                        "exact": true
                    }
                },
                {
                    "label": "Contacts",
                    "routerLink": "/sms/contacts"
                }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the filtering *after* the recursive call has identified which children to keep. If, after filtering, there still exist any child elements *or* the label matches, keep that parent item.

Something along the lines of:

```
private recursiveFilter(menuItems: MenuItem[], label: string, labelLower = label.toLowerCase()) {
    return menuItems.filter((item) => {
        if (item.items) item.items = recursiveFilter(item.items, label, labelLower);
        return item.label?.toLowerCase().includes(labelLower) || item.items?.length;
    });
}
```

Side-effects inside a `.filter` is a bit smelly, but I think it's the clearest way to approach this problem.

Live demo:

```js
const recursiveFilter = (menuItems, label) => (
    menuItems.filter((item) => {
        if (item.items) item.items = recursiveFilter(item.items, label);
        return item.label?.toLowerCase().includes(label) || item.items?.length;
    })
);

const topItem={label:"Messages",expanded:!1,items:[{label:"Dashboard",expanded:!1,routerLink:"/messages",visible:!0},{label:"Voicemail",expanded:!1,items:[{label:"Inbox",icon:"pi pi-fw pi-folder",routerLink:"/mailbox/inbox"},{label:"Archived",icon:"pi pi-fw pi-folder",routerLink:"/mailbox/archived"},{label:"Trash",icon:"pi pi-fw pi-folder",routerLink:"/mailbox/trash"}]},{label:"Text",expanded:!1,items:[{label:"Messages",routerLink:"/sms",routerLinkActiveOptions:{exact:!0}},{label:"Send",routerLink:"/sms/send",routerLinkActiveOptions:{exact:!0}},{label:"Contacts",routerLink:"/sms/contacts"}]}]};

topItem.items = recursiveFilter(topItem.items, 'send');
console.log(topItem);
```

Comment: Thanks, I agree it has to go with an approach like this.  I still can't get the code adopted to work though and it's wracking my mind.  I'd brute force it but we have potential infinite depth.  I'd love any example that I can see in a StackBlitz if possible.

Comment: Can you show your object structure, in the form of a JS object literal or JSON, so I can make a runnable snippet?

Comment: The `MenuItem` can be simplified down to having only two properties, a `label: string` and `items : MenuItem[]` for the children.  I am doing a string match on `label`.  I don't care if the code is TypeScript or JavaScript.

Comment: Could you post such an object in your question? A concrete input with the expected output helps things a whole lot (as always)

Comment: I have added the MenuItem JSON.

Comment: I made a live snippet, the approach looks to work

Answer (score 1):

I prefer separating out the recursive filtering from the specific check required.  Then  we can pass in a predicate function as needed.  I find this simpler.  So I might write it like this:

```js
const deepFilter = (pred) => ({items = [], ...rest}) => {
  const children = items .flatMap (deepFilter (pred))
  return (children .length || pred (rest)) 
    ? [{...rest, ...(items.length ? {items: children} : {})}] 
    : []
}

const matchLabel = (text) => ({label = ''}) => 
  label .toLowerCase () .includes (text .toLowerCase())

const filterByLabel = (t) =>
  deepFilter (matchLabel (t))

const menuItem = {label: "Messages", expanded: false, items: [{label: "Dashboard", expanded: false, routerLink: "/messages", visible: true}, {label: "Voicemail", expanded: false, items: [{label: "Inbox", icon: "pi pi-fw pi-folder", routerLink: "/mailbox/inbox"}, {label: "Archived", icon: "pi pi-fw pi-folder", routerLink: "/mailbox/archived"}, {label: "Trash", icon: "pi pi-fw pi-folder", routerLink: "/mailbox/trash"}]}, {label: "Text", expanded: false, items: [{label: "Messages", routerLink: "/sms", routerLinkActiveOptions: {exact: true}}, {label: "Send", routerLink: "/sms/send", routerLinkActiveOptions: {exact: true}}, {label: "Contacts", routerLink: "/sms/contacts"}]}]}


console .log ('labels containing "send":', filterByLabel ('send') (menuItem))
console .log ('labels containing "a":', filterByLabel ('a') (menuItem))
console .log ('labels containing "foobar":', filterByLabel ('foobar') (menuItem))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here, `deepFilter` takes a predicate function and returns a function which takes a tree with children nested as `items` and returns only those items matching the predicate or which have children matching the predicate.  We write the `matchLabel` predicate which takes a search string and returns a function which tests whether the object passed to it has a `label` property that (case-insensitively) contains the search term.  Finally, `filterByLabel` simply combines them, accepting a search term and returning a function which takes an item and (recursively) returns the item if it matches the term or if any of its children do.

### Variations

There are some things we might want to change.

- First of all, `matchLabel` is calling `.toLowerCase` on the text every time.  We could avoid that with this alternative:

  ```js
  const matchLabel = (t, text = t.toLowerCase()) => ({label = ''}) => 
    label .toLowerCase () .includes (text)
  ```
- Second, `deepFilter` is nice and generic... except that it hard-codes the tree structure of an `items` array in the function.  We might want to make that more generic by making that node name a parameter.  We can do so by

  ```js
  const deepFilter = (childName) => (pred) => ({[childName]: items = [], ...rest}) => {
    const children = items .flatMap (deepFilter (childName) (pred))
    return (children .length || pred (rest)) 
      ? [{...rest, ...(items.length ? {[childName]: children} : {})}] 
      : []
  }
  ```

  and then use it like this:

  ```js
  const filterByLabel = (t) =>
    deepFilter ('items') (matchLabel (t))
  ```

  or by naming the intermediate function:

  ```js
  const deepFilterItemTree = deepFilter ('items')

  const filterByLabel = (t) =>
    deepFilterItemTree (matchLabel (t))
  ```
- Third, if we happen to have handy a `compose` function, we might rewrite the main function as

  ```js
  const filterByLabel = compose (deepFilter, matchLabel)
  ```

  or if we took the second suggestion, as either of these:

  ```js
  const filterByLabel = compose (deepFilter ('items'), matchLabel)
  // or
  const filterByLabel = compose (deepFilterItemTree, matchLabel)
  ```

Comment: This is great stuff, thank you for the in-depth explanation also.  I also appreciate the small optimizations like getting out of the `toLower()` checks in a loop, although that won't affect us.